# express,mongoose ? trying to find all users

Tags: express, mongoose

Hi i am trying to fetch all users survyes on my app.  currently i have this in my back end api

```
module.exports = app => {
app.get('/api/surveys', async (req,res) =>{
const surveys= await Survey.find({_user: req.user}).select({
  recipients: false
});
res.send(surveys);
});

and this in my front end api 
export const fetchUser = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/current_user");

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

how can i make it so it will pull all users ?

Comment: Couldn't really get what you are trying to do here, your back-end api is for fetching all surveys while your redux action is for current_user 

I guess you are following Node with React: Stephen's course Am I correct ?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Answer (score 0):

Dont use any parameter in find(). If you use {_user: req.user} you will tell it to pull only data from this user out of the db.